# A linear algebra question(about vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove:
>   V is an infinite-dimensional vector space if and only if exist a vector sequence $ \mathbf v_1 ,\mathbf  v₂ ...∈V $,when $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer and $ \mathbf v₁ , ... ,\mathbf v$ₙ are linearly independent.

Comment: unfinite? Is it finite or typo?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think it means "infinite", for that's certainly the adjective that makes the theorem true.

Comment: I'm sorry.Just a spelling mistake.

Comment: It's an "if and only if" statement. Can you prove at least one of those two directions, 142088?

Comment: May I restate? "Prove that $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space if and only if, for every positive integer $n$, there's a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$." Alternatively: "Prove that $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space if and only if there's a sequence $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ such that for every positive integer $n$, the vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ form a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors." Which of these (if either!) is your question?

Comment: I can't...,Gerry.

Comment: Yes,thk you,John.

Comment: "Thank you" is not a response to a "which of A or B is correct?" question. Sigh.

Comment: The latter,John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is assumed to be known about finite-dimensional vector spaces, but this is my attempt:

Let $(v_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\{v_1, v_2, ...,v_n\}$ is a linearly independent set. Now, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a linearly independent subset of $V$ with more than $n$ vectors in it. So $dim(V) > n$

Conversely, let's assume that there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that no subset of $V$ with more than $n$ element is linearly independent (this is equivalent to the sequence being impossible to build. If you want to prove this, hint: every subset of a linaerly independent set is linearly independent). Then $dim(v) \leq n$